# С++ Убрать лишние запятые в строке

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Необходимо убрать лишние запятые в TextBox. Кальулятор с вещественными числами в Visual Studio c++. Не понимаю через какую функцию распознать наличие символа в строке. И как после оставить всего 1 символ, а лишние убрать. Пробовала через

```
if (txt1->Text->Contains(",")>1)
```

А дальше `Replace`?

Эту часть кода планирую вставить в KeyPress

```
> private: System::Void txt1_KeyPress(System::Object^ sender,
> System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^ e) {   if ((e->KeyChar < 7
> || e->KeyChar >57) && e->KeyChar != '.' && e->KeyChar != ',' &&
> e->KeyChar != '-')        e->Handled = true; }
> *if (txt1->Text->Contains(",")>1)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

строка string по сути является контейнером stl и к ней применимы алгоритмы stl. Я бы использовал для удаления запятых функцию remove_if (чтобы переместить все запятые в конец строки и получить итератор на первую запятую) в сочетании с erase (для того чтобы удалить из контейнера все запятые с помощью итератора).
Выглядит примерно так:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c) { return c == ','; }), str.end());
```

обратите внимание что для реализации этого метода необходимо подключить стандартную библиотеку algorithm.

Возможно, есть более изящные решения.